# How to exclude values within other values in recurrent searches using SQL

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I have a bunch of valid valued associated to operating systems and I need to detect which ones are showing up in a particular text column. Some of them are just an evolution of the original one, which is also included, like 1.'Windows 7 Professional' and 2.'Windows 7'.

The problem  is that whenever I find #1 in the description text, #2 also shows up, and it shouldn't.

I've tried flagging bigger text chains whenever they include a smaller record, but honestly don't know how to operate with that later (see current query after this one).

```sql
WITH vv1 (valid_values) AS (
        SELECT 'Windows 7'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Windows 7 Professional'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'MacOS'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Linux'::text
        )

    , vv2 AS ( SELECT * FROM vv1 )
    SELECT DISTINCT vv1.valid_values,CASE WHEN vv2.valid_values IS NOT NULL THEN vv2.valid_values END as includes 
    FROM vv1 LEFT OUTER JOIN vv2 ON (LOWER(vv1.valid_values) LIKE LOWER(vv2.valid_values)||'_%')
```

If you just execute this query (no db is required) you'll see the issue. The first row is "Windows 7".

```sql
WITH vv1 (valid_values) AS (
        SELECT 'Windows 7'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Windows 7 Professional'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'MacOS'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Linux'::text
        )

, txt (item_description) AS ( SELECT 'Computer with Linux or Windows 7 Professional'::text)

SELECT item_description, valid_values AS detected_os
FROM vv1, txt
WHERE item_description LIKE '%'||valid_values||'%'
```

The expected result is that valid values that are part of a bigger text chain don't show up when this bigger matches a result in the description field. In the example, "Windows 7" should not be a valid output since "Windows 7 Professional" has already matched the item description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the longest matching value.  However, the problem is that you need classes for the valid values.  So:

```
WITH vv1 (class, valid_values) AS (
        SELECT 'Windows'::text as class, 'Windows 7'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Windows'::text as class, 'Windows 7 Professional'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Mac'::text, 'MacOS'::text UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Linux'::text, 'Linux'::text
       )
SELECT txt.item_description, MAX(vv1.valid_values) AS detected_os
FROM vv1 JOIN
     txt
     ON txt.item_description LIKE '%' || vv1.valid_values || '%'
GROUP BY txt.item_description, vv1.class;
```

This returns at most one row per class -- the one with the longest match.

Comment: This worked perfectly, many thanks! Although in your example you forgot to declare the item_description :)

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify your logic by phrasing the problem as returning all valid values which do *not* appear as a substring of some other value:

```
SELECT valid_values
FROM vv1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vv1 t2
                  WHERE t2.valid_values LIKE t1.valid_values || '%' AND
                        t2.valid_values <> t1.valid_values);
```

### Demo

The logic used in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery would only return true if, for a given valid value in the outer table, we were able to find another value in the same CTE which shares the same prefix *and* also is not equal (which implies that it is a super string of the current valid value).